# Show AngularJS Dropdown Multiselect checkeds

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I was made a simple dropdownList using [AngularJS Dropdown Multiselect](http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/docs/#/main) and II'd like to show in page the names Ids checkeds but it is showing only the IDs.

[image]

How can I do It ?

Below or in my GitHub code:
**GitHub**: [all code here to download](https://github.com/frotaadriano/AngularJs-dropdownlist)

- Html page: index.html
- Angular app: "MyApp.js"
- DropDown directive: AngularJS Dropdown Multiselect

  **Html page: index.html**

  ```
  <h2>Multiselect dropdown with checkbox in angularjs</h2>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.js"></script>

          <!-- <script src="~/Scripts/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect.js"></script> -->
          <!-- <script src="~/Scripts/MyApp.js"></script> -->
          <script src="angularjs-dropdown-multiselect.js"></script>
          <script src="MyApp.js"></script> 
  <div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="multiselectdropdown">
      <div class="container" style="margin:50px">
          <form class="form-inline" name="myForm" role="form" ng-submit="SubmitData()">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Subscribe for categories : </label> 
                  <div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" extra-settings="dropdownSetting" 
                       options="Categories" selected-model="CategoriesSelected" checkboxes="true"></div>
                  <div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" extra-settings="dropdownSetting" 
                       options="Categories" selected-model="CategoriesSelected" styleActive="true"></div>

                  <div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" extra-settings="dropdownSetting" 
                       options="Categories" selected-model="CategoriesSelected2" styleActive="true"></div>

              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secoundary" ng-click="EnviarSelecionados()">Enviar Selecionados!</button>
          </form>
          <div>

              <h2>Show Selecteds</h2>

              <br/>
              <pre ng-repeat="catsel in CategoriesSelected">
              Person ID:{{catsel.id}} 
              <br/>
              Person Name:{{catsel.label}}
              </pre>      

          </div>

          <!-- <div style="margin-top:40px" ng-if="SubmittedCategories.length > 0"> -->
              <!-- <h2>Selected Categories</h2> -->
              <!-- <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered"> -->
                  <!-- <thead> -->
                      <!-- <tr> -->
                          <!-- <th>ID</th> -->
                          <!-- <th>Category Name</th> -->
                      <!-- </tr> -->
                  <!-- </thead> -->
                  <!-- <tbody> -->
                      <!-- <tr ng-repeat="cat in SubmittedCategories"> -->
                          <!-- <td>{{cat.CategoryID}}</td> -->
                          <!-- <td>{{cat.CategoryName}}</td> -->
                      <!-- </tr> -->
                  <!-- </tbody> -->
              <!-- </table>   -->
          <!-- </div> -->

          <div style="margin-top:40px" ng-if="SubmittedCategories.length > 0">
              <h2>Selected Categories</h2>
              <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
                  <thead>
                      <tr>
                          <th>ID</th>
                          <th>Category Name</th>
                      </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                      <tr ng-repeat="cat in SubmittedCategories">
                          <td>{{cat.CategoryID}}</td>
                          <td>{{cat.CategoryName}}</td>
                      </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>  
          </div> 
      </div>
  </div>
  ```

**Angular app: "MyApp.js"**

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['angularjs-dropdown-multiselect']);
app.controller('multiselectdropdown', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    //define object 
    $scope.CategoriesSelected = [];
    $scope.Categories = [];
    $scope.dropdownSetting = {
        scrollable: true,
        enableSearch: true, 
        scrollableHeight : '200px',
        closeOnBlur: false,
        showCheckAll: false,
        checkBoxes: false,
        displayProp: 'label', // se colocar id funciona 
        smartButtonMaxItems: 5
      }
    //fetch data from database for show in multiselect dropdown
    /*$http.get('/home/getcategories').then(function (data) {
        angular.forEach(data.data, function (value, index) {
            $scope.Categories.push({ id: value.CategoryID, label: value.CategoryName });
        });
    })*/

     $scope.Categories = [{id: 1, label: "David"}, {id: 2, label: "Jhon"}, {id: 3, label: "Danny"}];
     $scope.CategoriesSelected2 = [$scope.Categories[0], $scope.Categories[1]];

    //$scope.Categories.push({id: 1, label: "David"}, {id: 2, label: "Jhon"}, {id: 3, label: "Danny"});
    //post or submit selected items from multiselect dropdown to server
    $scope.SubmittedCategories = [];

    $scope.EnviarSelecionados = function(){
        var result = $scope.CategoriesSelected;
    }


    $scope.SubmitData = function () {
        var categoryIds = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.CategoriesSelected, function (value, index) {
            categoryIds.push(value.id);
        });

        var data = {
            categoryIds: categoryIds
        };

        /*$http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/home/savedata",
            data:JSON.stringify(data)
        }).then(function (data) {
            $scope.SubmittedCategories = data.data;
        }, function (error) {
            alert('Error');
        })*/
    }
}])
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, post the **actual code** in the question body.  Screenshots and links to 3rd party repositories are not a replacement for providing the code in an editable format.

Comment: Hello Claies. I try ed to post the code in boby of the post using the tool {} to post the code but it wasn't well in preview. So it was too late in the night and after a lot of minutes trying I gave up and post the pictures. I understand your point of view and I did it because I was run to an answer fast. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @AdrianoFrota you checked my answer?did it work? And as for formatting....you can paste your code first then select all code and then click the {} button to format it...

Comment: Thanks Himanshu Bansal!! The getFindObj(id) adjust works and now I Understand how to post the code and Ill try to adjust the post!!!

Comment: @AdrianoFrota always happy to help :) Feel free to drop ur questions if you run into any trouble...

Comment: Hello @Claies I removed the screenshots and post the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your `angularjs-dropdown-multiselect.js` file's getFindObj(id) function with this..

```
            function getFindObj(id) {
                var findObj = {};

                if ($scope.settings.externalIdProp === '') {
                    findObj[$scope.settings.idProp] = id;

                } else {
                    findObj[$scope.settings.externalIdProp] = id;
                    angular.forEach($scope.options, function (value, index) {
                        if(value.id == id){
                            findObj.label = value.label;
                        }
                    });
                }

                return findObj;
            }
```

I hope this will resolve your problem :)